# Tense of "break" when talking about a streak being interrupted

Tags: tense, american-english, present-perfect

> no matter how short but our dance competition streak **has broken**

I have tried broke, is broken too but none sound right

Comment: "has broken" is correct here. "is broke" means that it has no money. Welcome to the site by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No matter ... **but***

is not correct, and you'd also want to use a passive construction:

> No matter how short (it was), our dance competition winning streak has been
>   broken.

"No matter" is not quite idiomatic, however, since a clause headed by "no matter" would be complemented by a matrix clause which presents a *contrasting* idea, not a congruent idea. Compare the concession clause in these two versions:

> It may have been short, but our dance competition "winning streak" has been
>   broken.
>
> Although it was short, our dance competition "winning streak" has been broken.

Even there, the only contrast is the willingness to admit that it wasn't really a streak because it was so brief.

Here's a better contrast:

> No matter that our winning streak was short, it was glorious while it
>   lasted.
>
> No matter how short our winning streak was, it was glorious.
>
> Although it was short, our winning streak was glorious.